# How to Load an Order By Protected Code

Tags: magento2

I want to Load an Order By the Protected COde How I can do this

need Help. I am using `Magento 2.3.5`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Collection class `\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection` or `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface::getList` to get an order by `Protected COde`

### Here the sample code:

```
<?php

namespace Devamitbera\Sales\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class OrderByProtectedCode
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderRepository;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory
     */
    private $OrderCollectionFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $OrderCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->OrderCollectionFactory = $OrderCollectionFactory;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * Get Order using service contact
     */
    public function getOrderByRepository()
    {
        $protectCode = 'XXXXX';
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter('protect_code', $protectCode)
            ->setPageSize(1)
            ->setCurrentPage(1)
            ->create();
        $resultOrders = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

        if ($resultOrders->getTotalCount() > 0) {
            $orders = $resultOrders->getItems();
            /**
             * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
             */
            $order = array_shift(array_values($orders));
            // Want to full load order then use below code
            try {
                $orderFullLoad =  $this->orderRepository->get($order->getEntityId());
            } catch (NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
            }
        }
    }

    public function getOrderByCollection()
    {
        $protectCode = 'XXXXX';
        $orders = $this->OrderCollectionFactory->create();
        $orders->addAttributeToSelect('*'); // Select all fields but try to avoid *
        $orders->addAttributeToFilter('protect_code', $protectCode);
        $orders->setPageSize(1)->setCurPage(1);
        if ($orders->count() > 0) {
            $order = $orders->getFirstItem();
        }
    }
}
```